# Fontawsome Icon within a button without using hex code

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way in html to include the font awesome icon in a button element I tried the hex code and did not appear to work so I used the tag below

```html
<button id="btnRemoveFave_xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx" data-product-id="xxxx" type="button" class="btnRemoveFave" value="Remove From Favourites"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#f7296a"></i></button>
```

But I am find it hard to find the icon to change colour on fly and was going place it in the button itself as though might be easier to find its element than the i.

**Edit  2**

Reason why above does not work for me is I am trying to find it in a post using this

```
    var thisButton = $(this);
    thisButton.find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');
```

But its not changing my icon colour at all its on the click of the button I have it in in the following code.

```
<script>  

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".btnRemoveFave").click(function () {
                    var productId = $(this).data("product-id");
                    var customerId = $(this).data("customer-id");
                    var thisButton = $(this);

                       $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/RemoveFavouriteByCustId",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'custId': customerId, 'productCode': productId }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                            thisButton.find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');
                            console.log('do i get past here');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

**Edit 3**

This is the result of console.log this button

> [button#btnAddFave_YLXG20.btnAddFave, context: button#btnAddFave_YLXG20.btnAddFave]

Comment: Please make it in jsfiddle and share it

Comment: can you show us the hex code you tried ?

Comment: hi all js fiddle made above many thanks

Comment: I dont get what you try to achieve. Your code seems to achieve your goal

Comment: is this what you're after ? https://jsfiddle.net/5t2w0sj9/5/

Comment: @Stavm i made some more notes in my question to explain why

Comment: @Stavm how would one find that element then if you have a look at my second edit you see why was changing from nested element?

Comment: can you `console.log (thisButton)` just before you're invoking it ?

Comment: @Stavm please see above thank you edit 3 above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can add Fontawsome icons to the [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) :before.

There are two things you need to do.

1. Set the font family-family property to font awesome
2. Find the code for the font you want to use.

Your example has the heart, so it's `content: "\f004";`

Example:

```css
.btnRemoveFave:before {
  content: "\f004";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<button id="btnRemoveFave_xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx" data-product-id="xxxx" type="button" class="btnRemoveFave" value="Remove From Favourites">Remove From Favourites</button>
```

Reference for icon codes:
http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Comment: If you look at above i dont want to go that would as I need to change the icon color on success of a ajax post I modified my code above

Comment: i haz kode i need to use a different implementation so that question no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can, you can use :before or :after pseudo-elements. You can read more about them for instance [on W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp). `:before` will add your the hearth before your button's content, while `:after` will add after. The code `"\f004";` is taken from css of font-awesome icon's class. You can find it in font-awesome css file or simply by inspecting an icon made the normal way.

```css
#btnRemoveFave_xxxx:before{
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f004";
  color:#f7296a;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnRemoveFave_xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx" data-product-id="xxxx" type="button" class="btnRemoveFave" value="Remove From Favourites">test</button>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5foocut/

original question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45957030/3

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just add the fa icon within the opening and closing tag of button and make the background of button transparent

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style> 
    .myButton
    {
     background-color: transparent;
    }
   .fa{
     font-size:30px;
     color:#0099ff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="add-job" type="button" class="myButton" >
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already had it as a li your not showing anything of value here at all to the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
  
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="btnRemoveFave_xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx" data-product-id="xxxx" type="button" class="btnRemoveFave" value="&#xf004 Remove From Favourites" style="font-family:FontAwesome;"/>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Though I used Input Type "Button"  but hope it helps you